# "MyType" problem: Do I have to use abstract types (or generics) in Scala to return the actual class?

Tags: generics, scala

I am not sure if there is a better way of doing this:

```
trait Animal {
  val name: String
  val weight: Int

  type SubAnimal <: Animal

  def updateName(n: String) = returnMe(n, this.weight)
  def updateWeight(w: Int) = returnMe(this.name, w)
  // Abstract protected method
  protected def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): SubAnimal
}

case class Dog(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal {
  type SubAnimal = Dog
  override def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): Dog = Dog("Dog: " + name, w)
}
case class Cat(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal {
  type SubAnimal = Cat
  override def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): Cat = Cat("Cat: " + name, w)
}

val fido = Dog("Fido", 11)
println( fido )
val fido2 = fido.updateWeight(12)
println( fido2 )
```

When I run the code I get this output:

```
$ scala animal.scala 
Dog(Fido,11)
Dog(Dog: Fido,12)
```

I want to return the actual type of the animal in question after the `updateName` or `updateWeight` has been called (i.e. not `Animal`). I know that if I override `updateName` and `updateWeight` directly, then the correct type will be returned and I do not have to use the abstract type `SubAnimal`.

Is there some tricky way of escaping the abstract type for the special case where the value of the abstract type is the **same as the subclass**?

(This is know as the "MyType" problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some [recent discussion](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6649) on this topic... What you're looking for is commonly referred to as "MyType", and the typical Scala/Java encoding for it uses recursive type parameters:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable { 
    public final int compareTo(E o) 
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: So the magic way would be to use "this.type" (from your link) but since I am returning a new instance (not this) then it is not possible. Later in the post Odersky recommends abstract types for this problem, so I guess that ends the discussion. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, this.type is too narrow to act as MyType: it's the type of this *but no other instance of this's class*.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
trait Animal[T] {
  self:T =>

  val name: String
  val weight: Int

  def updateName(n: String): T = returnMe(n, this.weight)
  def updateWeight(w: Int): T = returnMe(this.name, w)
  // Abstract protected method
  protected def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): T
}

case class Dog(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal[Dog] {
  override def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): Dog = Dog("Dog: " + name, w)
}

case class Cat(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal[Cat] {
   override def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): Cat = Cat("Cat: " + name, w)
}
```

Something like `case class Cat(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal[Dog]` gets rejected by the compiler. Code <strike>stolen</strike> adapted from http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/12/10/self-help/

Comment: Hi @Landei, I do not see the difference between this and the solution provided by @one-zero-zero-one. Why is the self:T => Part needed? When I take it away I get the same output.

Comment: @olle: The behavior is the same as in one-zero-zero-one's solution, it's just easier to read. Without the self:T part, you can write `case class Cat(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal[Int]`, which clearly shouldn't be allowed. For details see the link I provided.

Answer (score 6):

Using type parametrization?

```
trait Animal[A <: Animal[A]] {
  val name: String
  val weight: Int

  def updateName(n: String) = returnMe(n, this.weight)
  def updateWeight(w: Int) = returnMe(this.name, w)
  // Abstract protected method
  protected def returnMe(n: String, w: Int): A
}

case class Dog(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal[Dog] {
  override def returnMe(n: String, w: Int) = Dog("Dog: " + name, w)
}

case class Cat(name: String, weight: Int) extends Animal[Cat] {
  override def returnMe(n: String, w: Int) = Cat("Cat: " + name, w)
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. your solution is probably what "abstract types" was meant to simplify. I consider "type parametrization" just as bad/good as "abstract types" in this case. You agree?

Comment: @olle: I never understood the point of abstract type members and I never use them in my own code. I think of them as unnecessary redundancy in the language. (Paul P recently expressed similar thoughts at mailing list.)

Comment: You are correct, abstract types seem to be pure sugar. But I for one like them very much, since i think it is easier to think about a "type field" that you can override in the subclass, than the corresponding type parameter syntax.

Comment: Abstract types are not just syntactical sugar. While you can often turn one the abstract type version into a generic one and vice versa, they are not equivalent: If you have Foo[X], every instantiation like Foo[Int] establishes a new type. If you have Foo{ type X }, there is only one Foo type, which happens to contain a abstract type variable.