# Why doesn't this code compile? Is this really unsafe?

Tags: scala

Consider this simple binary tree type:

```
abstract class BinaryTree[T] {
  type Repr <: BinaryTree[T]

  def left: Repr
  def value: T
  def right: Repr

  def height: Int

 def add(elem: T): Repr = 
    if ( left.height <= right.height ) copy( left.add( elem ), right)
    else copy( left, right.add(elem))

 def copy( left: Repr, right: Repr ) : Repr
}

abstract class BinarySearchTree[T] extends BinaryTree[T] {
  type Repr <: BinarySearchTree[T]

  def ordering: Ordering[T]

  override def add(elem: T) = 
    if ( ordering.equiv( elem, value ) ) this.asInstanceOf[Repr]
    else if ( ordering.lt(elem, value) ) copy( left.add( elem ), right )
    else copy( left, right.add( elem ) )
}


class ScapegoatTree[T]( val value: T, val left: ScapegoatTree[T], val right: ScapegoatTree[T] )(implicit val ordering: Ordering[T])
  extends BinarySearchTree[T] {

  type Repr = ScapegoatTree[T]

  def add = this /* snip */

  def copy( left: ScapegoatTree[T], right: ScapegoatTree[T] ) = new ScapegoatTree( value, left, right )
}

class BalancedBinaryTree[T]( val value: T, val left: BalancedBinaryTree[T], val right: BalancedBinaryTree[T] )(implicit val ordering: Ordering[T])
  extends BinarySearchTree[T] {

  type Repr = BalancedBinaryTree[T]

  def add = this /* snip */

  def copy( left: BalancedBinaryTree[T], right: BalancedBinaryTree[T] ) = new BalancedBinaryTree( value, left, right )
}
```

Using Scala 2.9 in Scala-IDE, the add method fails to compile because copy takes a `Repr` while `left.add(elem)` and `right.add(elem)` return a `Repr#Repr`. As far as I can tell, `Repr#Repr` must always be a subtype of `Repr`, and therefore it should be safe. Have I failed to consider some case, or is this one of those fortunately rare instances where the type system prevents you from doing something that ought to work?

Also, is there any way I could change my type definition so this would be legal, or assert to the compiler that `Repr#Repr` must be a subtype of `Repr` (aside from a cast, I mean).  I'm still getting used to Scala and I'm not sure I've fully comprehended the type system yet. I did get it to compile by writing an implicit method that does a cast, but that feels like more of a workaround than a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: I should add that in my actual implementation of this I have subclasses that further restrict the type of Repr, if that makes a difference.

Edit 2: Added more code, as requested. This issue appears in the `BinarySearchTree` type as well, but not in concrete implementations such as `ScapegoatTree` where `Repr` is specified. There is also a concrete implementation of the basic `BinaryTree`, but I'm trying to keep it minimal so you don't have to wade through too much unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried a rewritten using type parameters instead of abstract types, hope it suite your need.

```
trait BinaryTree[T, Repr <: BinaryTree[T, Repr]] {
  def left: Repr
  def value: T
  def right: Repr

  def height: Int
  def add(elem: T): Repr =  
    if ( left.height <= right.height ) copy( left.add( elem ), right)
    else copy( left, right.add(elem))

  def copy( l: Repr, r: Repr ) : Repr
}

trait BinarySearchTree[T, U<:BinarySearchTree[T,U]] extends BinaryTree[T, U] { self:U =>
  def ordering: Ordering[T]

  override def add(elem: T) = 
    if ( ordering.equiv( elem, value ) ) self
    else if ( ordering.lt(elem, value) ) copy( left.add( elem ), right )
    else copy( left, right.add( elem ) )
}

class ScapegoatTree[T]( val value: T, val left: ScapegoatTree[T], val right: ScapegoatTree[T] )(implicit val ordering: Ordering[T]) extends BinarySearchTree[T, ScapegoatTree[T]] {
  override def height = 1
  override def copy( left: ScapegoatTree[T], right: ScapegoatTree[T] ) = new ScapegoatTree( value, left, right )
}

class BalancedBinaryTree[T]( val value: T, val left: BalancedBinaryTree[T], val right: BalancedBinaryTree[T] )(implicit val ordering: Ordering[T]) extends BinarySearchTree[T, BalancedBinaryTree[T]]{
  override def height = 1
  override def copy( left: BalancedBinaryTree[T], right: BalancedBinaryTree[T] ) = new BalancedBinaryTree( value, left, right )
}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962219/mytype-problem-do-i-have-to-use-abstract-types-or-generics-in-scala-to-retu), you are encounting a 'MyType' problem.

Comment: Well, that does allow BinaryTree to compile, but I have subclasses that further restrict the type of Repr, and this change causes them to start showing the a similar error. I tried adding a copy method with the Repr of the subclasses, but that just overloaded the method.

Comment: Then maybe you can post your subclass code as it is difficult to find an answer without knowing what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Done. When I tried to change copy to take BinaryTree[T]#Repr, BinaryTree can compile but BinarySearchTree starts giving an error that it needs a BinaryTree[T]#Repr but it found a BinarySearchTree.this.Repr.