# Scala: Why does the following give a type mismatch error?

Tags: scala, types

I have the following code snippet:

```
class Statistics[T, U <: NumberLike[T]] {
  def mean(xs: Vector[U]): U =
    xs.reduce(_ + _) / xs.size
}

trait NumberLike[T] {
  def + (that: NumberLike[T]): NumberLike[T]
  def / (that: Int): NumberLike[T]
}
```

It compiles with the error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : NumberLike[T]
 required: U
    xs.reduce(_ + _) / xs.size
                ^
one error found
```

I don't understand why the compiler does not accept this; I've already defined that `U` should be a subclass of `NumberLike[T]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says exactly what went wrong: your `mean` method promised to return `U`, but instead it returns a `NumberLike[T]`.

You could solve it by F-bounded polymorphism:

```
class Statistics[T, U <: NumberLike[T, U]] {
  def mean(xs: Vector[U]): U =
    xs.reduce(_ + _) / xs.size
}

trait NumberLike[T, Res <: NumberLike[T, Res]] {
  def + (that: NumberLike[T, Res]): Res
  def / (that: Int): Res
}
```

This works, because now `NumberLike` carries around the precise return type of `+` and `/`. Instead of returning some underspecified `NumberLike`, it now guarantees to return a `Res`.

Since you don't seem to use the type `T` anywhere, it is actually much clearer if you omit `T` altogether:

```
class Statistics[U <: NumberLike[U]] {
  def mean(xs: Vector[U]): U =
    xs.reduce(_ + _) / xs.size
}

trait NumberLike[U <: NumberLike[U]] {
  def + (that: NumberLike[U]): U
  def / (that: Int): U
}
```

Notice that now `+` returns an `U`, not merely some unrelated `NumberLike[T]`.

---

Actually, you should consider separating the functionality (addition, division) from the syntactic sugar of the operators. You can move the actual computations into a separate typeclass, and provide the `+`, `/` methods by an implicit class:

```
/* The operations */
trait NumberTypeclass[U] {
  def add(a: U, b: U): U
  def divideByInt(a: U, i: Int): U
}

/* The syntactic sugar */
implicit class NumberOps[U: NumberTypeclass](u: U) {
  def +(other: U): U = implicitly[NumberTypeclass[U]].add(u, other)
  def /(i: Int): U = implicitly[NumberTypeclass[U]].divideByInt(u, i)
}

/* Usage example */
class Statistics[U: NumberTypeclass] {
  def mean(xs: Vector[U]): U = {
    xs.reduce(_ + _) / xs.size
  }
}
```

At the first glance, it is slightly more verbose, but it has the advantage that you can omit the complicated F-bounded polymorphism, and that you can provide different syntax styles for the same functionality. Typeclasses also tend to compose better than complex class hierarchies with F-bounded polymorphism.

Comment: Funny you mention typeclasses, because I wrote the above code as a learning exercise for myself on why typeclasses are useful.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a bit misleading, but if you look closely the `^` is on the `+`, meaning the return type of that operation is wrong.

The issue is with the fact that `+` and `/` are operations that return `NumberLike[T]`, but you're requiring `U` as the return type of `mean`.

Since functions are covariant in their return type, you cannot return a `NumberLike` where `U` is expected.

With this in mind, you can probably work around this by making sure your `NumberLike` operations return a more precise type:

```
trait NumberLike[T] {
  def +[A <: NumberLike[T]](that: A): A
  def /[A <: NumberLike[T]](that: Int): A
}
```

Now your definition of `mean` should compile.

Answer (score 0):

In `reduce` it is expected that the binary operator has a uniform signature, in this case `(U, U) => U`, although in your case that is `(U, NumberLike[T]) => NumberLike[T]`.

This won't work even if you fixes the trait, because of the expected result type in `mean`, `+`, `/`. You told it should be `U` in `mean`, while the `+`, `/` methods in `NumberLike` return `NumberLike[T]` values, not the subtype of it. (Scala does not support MyTypes, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962219/mytype-problem-do-i-have-to-use-abstract-types-or-generics-in-scala-to-retu) might be interesting for you.)